# Getting compiler Exception "Expression Expected" C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, visual-studio-2019

I have a list of objects, which I'm trying to sort based on a integer property of object using OrderBy in C#.
While I'm trying to build the code, I get an error "expression expected". Unable to figure out what's the reason behind this.

```cs
List<Result> objResultList = new List<Result>();
jQueryObject inspFormData = jQuery.Select(".InspFormLabel");
int i = 0;
foreach (Element node in inspFormData.GetElements())
{
    Result objResult = new Result();
    objResult.FormQuestion = node.FirstChild.InnerText;
    objResult.FormAnswer = Script.Literal("node.lastChild.value").ToString();
    objResult.QuestionNumber = i++;
    objResultList.Add(objResult);
}
objResultList.OrderBy(r => r.QuestionNumber);
string finalOutput = Json.Stringify(objResultList);
Script.Literal("console.log(finalOutput)");
```

Here's the Result Class:-

```cs
class Result
{
    [PreserveCase]
    public string FormQuestion = string.Empty;
    [PreserveCase]
    public string FormAnswer = string.Empty;
    [PreserveCase]
    public int QuestionNumber = 0;
}
```

I'm Using VS 2019 for coding and LangVersion is set to preview. I tried setting LangVersion to 3 as well for my project but that doesn't make any difference.

Here's the reference list:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGGno.png)

Comment: On which line are you getting your error? Also, by langversion preview do you mean 8.0?

Comment: Why is this tagged `C#-3.0`? VS 2008 which included C# 3 is a long time ago...

Comment: Richard:- While giving lambda expression, I initially got the error that lambda feature isn't supported for C#2, try using C#3 or above. Then I tried changing langVersion to 3 then Preview which didn't make any difference even, hence I tagged C#3.0 as well.

Comment: MindSwipe:- objResultList.OrderBy(r=>r.QuestionNumbers)

Comment: Can you tell me what nuget packge you installed or which reference you are using?

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT I haven't installed any Nuget package. Regarding references, I have added image of those in my question.

Comment: Based on my search, I could not find the reference shown in the picture you provided. How do you add these references?